# Is it possible to mute your computer through the command-line interface?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, audio, mute

Currently, I can press the mute button on my keyboard, making my sound turn off. Is it possible to do this through cmd.exe so that I can run it with other things I have in that program?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It isn't possible to mute it directly through the command line, no. 
But you could use a command line utility such as [NirCmd](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/nircmd.html) to achieve the same functionality.
Simply running `nircmd.exe mutesysvolume 1` from cmd would mute the audio. E.g. you could easily do this through a batch script, if you're trying to do several things at once.

Comment: third party app?

Comment: Yes. There is a way with PowerShell, but it's messier.