# NirCmd won't copy to windows directory

Tags: windows-7, nircmd

I was suggested to use NirCmd from [this quesiton](https://superuser.com/questions/452206/is-it-possible-to-mute-your-computer-through-the-command-line-interface). However, when I pressed the "Copy to windows directory" button, I got this error. Why?

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to copy the directory where NirCMD is located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't running Nircmd as an administrator. righ-click it and click "run as administrator."

Comment: Thanks, I don't know why I didn't think to do this earlier.